# Redirect combinations in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have my domain with a ssl certificate, I want to redirect everything to use https://www.example.com (with https and www)

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1
```

However, this two combinations don't work and shows apache2 default page:

```
http://example.com 
http://www.example.com
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
# line above to catch any request with http regradless of having www or not
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
# line above to catch any request with https and without www 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

So , any request with (`http` or `https`) and (`www` or none `www`) will be redirected to `https://www.example.com`

**Note:** clear your browser cache and test it , if Ok , change `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection